# using the .at[ ] and .iat[ ] accessors in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

whenever I iterate though a pandas series on jupyter notebook console to modify values using set_value I get this FutureWarning: set_value is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use .at[] or .iat[] accessors instead.

How do I use .at[] or .iat[] in loops?

```
s = pd.Series([100 , 120.0 , 101.0 , 3.0 ])
for l , v in s.iteritems():
    s.set_value(l, v + 4)
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand the purpose of using set_value or iat as you are uniformly modifying the entire series.

Answer (score 4):

You want something like:

```
In [14]: import pandas as pd

In [15]: s = pd.Series([100 , 120.0 , 101.0 , 3.0 ])
    ...:

In [16]: for l, v in s.iteritems():
    ...:     s.at[l] = v + 4
    ...:

In [17]: s
Out[17]:
0    104.0
1    124.0
2    105.0
3      7.0
dtype: float64
```

However, this is very un-*pandonic*, rather, you should always prefer vectorized operations:

```
In [18]: s = pd.Series([100 , 120.0 , 101.0 , 3.0 ])
    ...:

In [19]: s += 4

In [20]: s
Out[20]:
0    104.0
1    124.0
2    105.0
3      7.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: As a side question is using the underlying numpy array (s.values) to set values a bad practice (un-*pandonic*)?

Comment: @DanielMesejo I mean, I don't really see a reason to. I'd have to consider a specific use-case. Most of the operations you would use on an array are simply passed through the pandas data-frame, albeit, sometimes with non-significant overhead. Fundamentally, the issue is that you should prefer vectorized operations over manual, python-level looping.

Comment: @DanielMesejo You should be careful when using the `.values` to assign values because it no longer uses the index for alignment. In this case the first value of the array is assigned to the first index. This can be problematic when you `.groupby` or `.sort_values` which can output a Series with a different index ordering than the original.

Comment: @ALollz also, I think in some cases it will *not* modify the `pandas` object. Say, if you have mixed dtypes in a `DataFrame`.